# Generating function for a bin that has either no elements or 2 only?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

What is the generating function for a bin that has either zero elements or 2 only?

We start with: $(1+x^2)$ which if it had an $x$ it would translate to $\frac {1-x^3}{1-x}$ So I thought maybe I could represent $(1+x^2)$ like so: $(1+x^2)=(1+x+x^2)-((1+x)-(1))$. I know what first two translate to but what $(1)$ translate to? (It's an empty bin) is it: $\frac {1-x}{1-x}=1$?

So the generating function for $(1+x^2)$ would be: $\frac {1-x^3}{1-x} - \frac {1-x^2}{1-x} +1$?

Comment: What? The generating function is $1+x^2$. What's the point of everything after that?

Comment: But $(1+x^2)$ isn't the expression that you can get coefficients from no? @Batman

Comment: what? You can have another expression, but it has to be equal to $1+x^2$. If you were building up a generating function for something more complicated using this, you may want it to simplify the overall generating function, but generally you'll start with $1+x^2$ and then start tweaking from there.

Comment: Suppose we have $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3$ so we could write that as: $\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}$ right? So what I'm asking is how to go from $f(x)=1+x^2$ to its equivalent expression. @Batman

Comment: $1+x^2 = \dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x^2} =  \dfrac{(1+x^2)(1-x^2)}{(1+x)(1-x)}=  \dfrac{1-x+x^2-x^3}{1-x}$ but, while pretty, these are unlikely to help unless you are adding them to something with a common denominator

Comment: Well the common denominator thing isn't so important given that you usually multiply generating functions, making $1+x^2$ vastly preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question was counting the number of ways of distributing $n$ indistinguishable balls among $m$ distinguishable bins so each bin had $0$ or $2$ balls, the answer would be the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x^2)^m$.

If you let $m=1$, you are left with looking at one bin and the generating function $(1+x^2)$.

There is one way of distributing $0$ indistinguishable balls so the bin has $0$ or $2$ balls (the coefficient of $x^0$) and one way of distributing $2$ indistinguishable balls so the bin has $0$ or $2$ balls (the coefficient of $x^2$), and no ways of distributing any other number of balls so the bin has $0$ or $2$ balls.  It does not get any more complicated than that, and you do not need to complicate $(1+x^2)$.